# How to use Video View to play multiple videos in different layouts and activities

Tags: android, android-videoview

I wanted to play 3 videos from my phone in the app using Video View. The first two videos are working amazing, but then, when I try to open the third video it just crashes/plays the first video.

I tried switching the third video with the first to see if I have a problem with the video itself. The third video now worked fine, but the first video didn't work and either crashed the app or showed the third video (because I switched locations with the 3rd).

If it matters: the first and second videos are about 240MB and the third is about 80MB, all of the videos are in MP4, and I have all the required permissions.

To add more to this, the 3rd activity and layout is just a copy of the first one.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the problem. The problem was that I copied the layout and activity.
I just need to create new one and stop being lazy.
Instead of copy pasting the files, I need to just copy and paste the stuff in the files, and create new files.